# Winston Log Daily Roll

Tags: node.js, winston

I have my log files rolling and appending with the correct date format.

```
 foo.log.2014-10-02
 foo.log.2014-10-03
```

but I was wondering if I could create a situation where my most current log always had a consistent name. For example

```
foo.log
foo.log.2014-10-02
foo.log.2014-10-03
```

Here foo.log would represent the log for 10-04

or

```
foo.log
foo.log.2014-10-02
foo.log.2014-10-03
foo.log.2014-10-04
```

Here foo.log would represent the log for 10-05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do this with the current implementation of the `winston` module. However, you could fork the module and edit the [DailyRotateFile transport](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/daily-rotate-file.js) to implement this. All you'd need to do is rename the file that is currently used, and edit the file renaming when the file rolls over.